# Sankey diagram with timeseries data

Tags: mysql, sql, sankey-diagram

Suppose I have the following timeseries data tracking events:

[image]

(Note the `Timestamp` is a full datetime.) Would it be possible to build a Sankey diagram in SQL based on the above three fields, or is this a graph that can't really be done in SQL but needs server-side code to properly implement? Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/kxhoyeb5/.

[image]

Comment: "Would it be possible to build a Sankey diagram in SQL..." -- Not really. SQL is a database language to store and retrieve data fast and efficiently. Any further *massaging* of the data is better done in the app or presentation layers.

Comment: What you could do is to assemble in SQL a JSON document with all the data. Then the javascript library could use it more easily.

Comment: Building the JSON input for the chart is easy.

Comment: @gotqn -- sure, could you please show an example of the `from,to,weight` query?

Comment: select userid as from, event as to, count (*) as weight from table group by userid, event

Comment: @gotqn no it needs to go from event to event. I.e., `WatchVideo -> PurchaseItem`

Comment: @David542 Could you show me the desire output? Base on your example I built the query above.